# How to write to a specific log file from management command?

Tags: django, logging

I have a Django 1.3 application. I have several management commands. I want each command to write, to a different logfile, instead of default filename defined in settings.py. I run these commands as part of cron everyday. Our current logfile looks like the example given here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/. And, we use

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean the `management commands`?Do you just want to divide the logfile daily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do this by adding a logger and a handler for each package:

```
'handlers': {
    'my_command_handler': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/path/to/my_command_log',
     },
     ...
},
'loggers': {
     'my_pkg.management.commands.my_command': {
         'level': 'DEBUG',
         'handlers': ['my_command_handler'],
     },
     ...
 }
```

You may also want to consider adding `'propagate': False` to the command loggers, if you don't want the messages to get to other loggers.

Comment: I tried this, and log statements in the command module indeed end up in the desired file. However, log statements in (shared) modules _called_ by the management command, do not end up in the desired file; they go to the 'default' log file.
Is there any way to also make log statements from shared modules go to the correct file (i.e. the one defined for the command, if trigger by a command run; and the main one, if triggered by the webserver like Apache or gunicorn)?